# How can I load all Media of a certain type?

Tags: 8, media

I am trying to load all media items of a certain type but I can't find how to.

Is there a way to set a filtering type on something like

```
$media = Media::loadMultiple();
```

Or do you have to load all media and then filter manually?

Comment: How about using views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use entity query you can filter the entities by type before uploading them.

```
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('media')
  ->condition('bundle', 'YOUR_TYPE')
  ->execute();

$medias = Media::loadMultiple($ids);
```

Comment: You may need to add `use Drupal\media\Entity\Media;`